# How to return max date based on two other columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, maxdate

I haven't been able to track down an answer to this problem, so I am hoping someone here can help.  I need to return the max date for each course, for each ID. I have been using a subquery to pick the max date based from one other column, but cannot seem to find a way to have it take into account both columns. Data would look something like this:

```
ID    Course    CourseDate
1     DD        1/14/2013
1     DD        1/16/2013
1     CC        2/22/2013
1     CC        2/15/2013
2     DD        1/16/2013
```

I am hoping to get a result that would look like this:

```
ID    Course    CourseDate
1     DD        1/16/2013
1     CC        2/22/2013
2     DD        1/16/2013
```

Thank you very much for any help!  It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT  ID, Course, MAX(CourseDATE) MAx_DATE
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY ID, Course
```

Comment: It was just that easy apparently. I was trying to make it harder than it needed to be.  Thank you for the response!